# Check web site speed without advertising

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I need to check the web site speed excluding the adv. Do you know if exists some tool than can help me for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ad blocker addon on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Google PageSpeed ​​Insights. Another alternative tool that you can use is GTmetrix. There are several analysis options, like browser, server, connection, adblock, onload, and video. [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/).